# Interpretation if my data is Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, python, histogram

I have business data, which only occur from Monday to Friday.

To know if I can run statistical tests, I want to check if I have a Gaussian distribution. Therefore I am using a histogram and a qqplot:
[image]

[image]

I think the first histogram occurs because of the zero days. Would it be statistically ok to exclude these days?

And then still use statistical techniques to check for correlation with another dataset (if I also exclude it there?) Or am I missing something?

And this current distribution is not Gaussian?

Comment: I wouldn't describe your distribution as Gaussian (normal) at all. The only reason for excluding the zeros would be that they are known to be irrelevant to your goal.

Comment: what is the reason you think it is not normal at all?

Comment: It's highly skewed, there is an an enormous gap and the normal quantile plot is far from linear. It's hard to know when you are a beginner quite how much misfit disqualifies a distribution as inappropriate, but here is a way to push forward. You have, if I count correctly, 31 data points. What you should do is simulate several samples of size 31 from a normal distribution and draw a normal quantile plot for each. Then you will see that your data are very far from what you ever get with a parent normal.

Comment: Telling you how to do that in your software is for me as you don't state what software you use although I can see that is not software I use.

Comment: I am using python, but I got your point, thx!

Comment: Also try running a few parameter free tests. Try Kolmogorov Smirnhov, Shapiro Wilk or Chi Square. You distribution is highly skewed. With those tests you got some evidence. Maybe you can exclude the zeros with business logic.

Comment: this tests on top told me that probably it is not gaussian, thx

Comment: I disagree with @mischva11 Tests are futile here: it's not Gaussian. But if you want a test standard English spellings are Kolmogorov-Smirnov (a poor test for normality, but you need to supply not estimate parameters and it's not sensitive enough in the tails) and Shapiro-Wilk (a better one). Chi-square is a lousy test for normality, although it is found in texts some decades old or out-of-date.

Comment: You're interested in correlations: that is the only procedure you mention. What do you want to correlate with this variable? It could well be this distribution being non-normal is irrelevant to that goal.